# Ggplot into latex using tizkdevice

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm a newbie of latex. I want to import a plot from R made with ggplot. I use package tizkdevice. 
In r everything seems to work fine. 
In latex when i compile this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

    \input{plot_test.tex}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have these error

[image]

This is the plot_test.tex generated by R

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.10.1 on 2017-01-06 12:03:19
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (361.35,361.35);
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (361.35,361.35);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.6pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (361.35,361.35);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 18.58, 18.58) rectangle ( 47.35,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] ( 18.58, 18.58) rectangle ( 47.35,338.79);

\path[] ( 50.72,139.44) -- ( 32.96,178.68);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{50,78,104}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.95] at ( 54.44,124.47) {crooked};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at ( 54.46,181.70) {president};

\path[] ( 42.68,174.48) -- ( 32.96,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at ( 58.05,162.70) {megynkelly};

\path[] ( 32.41,152.64) -- ( 32.96,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.13] at ( 32.30,143.33) {bad};

\path[] ( 39.74,312.20) -- ( 32.96,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.57] at ( 39.92,313.70) {cnn};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 52.85, 18.58) rectangle ( 81.63,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] ( 52.85, 18.58) rectangle ( 81.63,338.79);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{25,9,140}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.13] at ( 76.34,160.77) {york};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.06] at (-26.96,170.52) {makeamericagreatagain};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at ( 61.48,182.08) {people};

\path[] ( 67.08,223.32) -- ( 67.24,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at ( 67.06,224.83) {vote};

\path[] ( 67.29,156.21) -- ( 67.24,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at ( 67.30,146.29) {am};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 87.13, 18.58) rectangle (115.91,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] ( 87.13, 18.58) rectangle (115.91,338.79);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{50,78,104}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  3.41] at ( 55.49,171.91) {crooked};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.76] at ( 75.71,156.68) {bernie};

\path[] ( 80.21,150.87) -- (101.52,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.50] at ( 72.46,132.15) {sanders};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.13] at ( 95.71,186.74) {bad};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.83] at (100.58,145.49) {isis};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (121.41, 18.58) rectangle (150.19,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (121.41, 18.58) rectangle (150.19,338.79);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{46,97,145}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  3.08] at ( 94.98,180.68) {nytimes};

\path[] (122.61,150.72) -- (135.80,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.13] at (118.43,134.52) {failing};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.10] at (119.76,160.17) {media};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (130.13,201.55) {story};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at (130.04,183.11) {people};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (155.69, 18.58) rectangle (184.46,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (155.69, 18.58) rectangle (184.46,338.79);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{40,81,119}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.50] at (139.07,162.98) {america};

\path[] (154.69,199.07) -- (170.07,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.06] at (148.19,200.57) {indiana};

\path[] (156.82,158.46) -- (170.07,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.03] at (151.25,142.98) {warren};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (166.31,163.39) {vote};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at (152.24,183.01) {elizabeth};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (189.96, 18.58) rectangle (218.74,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (189.96, 18.58) rectangle (218.74,338.79);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{43,78,112}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.68] at (191.13,166.55) {vote};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.30] at (161.12,168.44) {drainthesw};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.83] at (197.91,192.71) {time};

\path[] (196.04,209.85) -- (204.35,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (194.21,211.36) {florida};

\path[] (198.33,161.38) -- (204.35,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (195.95,149.21) {watch};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (224.24, 18.58) rectangle (253.02,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (224.24, 18.58) rectangle (253.02,338.79);

\path[] (258.49,197.94) -- (238.63,178.68);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{57,90,122}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  3.01] at (270.73,199.44) {debate};

\path[] (253.06,215.58) -- (238.63,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.78] at (257.39,217.09) {team};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.23] at (179.28,169.01) {bigleaguetruth};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.75] at (220.40,163.00) {america};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (264.64,181.67) {mikepence};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (258.52, 18.58) rectangle (287.30,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (258.52, 18.58) rectangle (287.30,338.79);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{65,90,114}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.58] at (240.88,180.52) {crooked};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.60] at (275.53,148.12) {wall};

\path[] (264.33,202.81) -- (272.91,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.60] at (261.83,204.32) {people};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.30] at (262.62,165.17) {country};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at (266.77,182.71) {border};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (292.80, 18.58) rectangle (321.57,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (292.80, 18.58) rectangle (321.57,338.79);

\path[] (298.67,158.70) -- (307.18,178.68);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{78,106,132}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (295.60,145.82) {florida};

\path[] (298.73,181.39) -- (307.18,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (276.26,182.90) {americafirst};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (304.37,162.39) {ohio};

\path[] (300.58,198.79) -- (307.18,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.43] at (298.46,200.30) {people};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.37] at (297.08,181.82) {tonight};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (327.07, 18.58) rectangle (355.85,338.79);
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[fill=fillColor] (327.07, 18.58) rectangle (355.85,338.79);

\path[] (319.30,199.15) -- (341.46,178.68);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{102,144,183}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.66] at (307.76,200.66) {america};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.83] at (345.10,157.02) {join};

\path[] (333.70,190.74) -- (341.46,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at (329.43,192.25) {tonight};

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at (314.64,175.93) {americafirst};

\path[] (329.49,152.50) -- (341.46,178.68);

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.13] at (327.01,143.18) {imwithyou};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 18.58,338.79) rectangle ( 47.35,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 18.58,338.79) rectangle ( 47.35,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 32.96,344.29) {topic0};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 52.85,338.79) rectangle ( 81.63,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 52.85,338.79) rectangle ( 81.63,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 67.24,344.29) {topic1};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] ( 87.13,338.79) rectangle (115.91,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 87.13,338.79) rectangle (115.91,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (101.52,344.29) {topic2};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (121.41,338.79) rectangle (150.19,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (121.41,338.79) rectangle (150.19,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (135.80,344.29) {topic3};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (155.69,338.79) rectangle (184.46,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (155.69,338.79) rectangle (184.46,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (170.07,344.29) {topic4};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (189.96,338.79) rectangle (218.74,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (189.96,338.79) rectangle (218.74,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (204.35,344.29) {topic5};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (224.24,338.79) rectangle (253.02,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (224.24,338.79) rectangle (253.02,355.85);
\definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

\node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (238.63,344.29) {topic6};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\path[clip] (258.52,338.79) rectangle (287.30,355.85);
\definecolor{draw}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: When i open  plot_test.tex in texmaker pops up a message about correct encoding.

Comment: There clearly is a problem with the `plot_test.tex` file, it seems truncated. It ends midway at a `\definecolor{draw}` command, without closing a bunch of environments.

Answer (score 2):

Your plot file seems to be incomplete : the last scope is not ended, nor the `\begin{tikzpicture}` environment. I tried to remove the last scope and add `end{tikzpicture}` at the end, and it compiles (but the picture is really strange ^^').

The picture (maybe with a complete file it would looks better ?):
[image: result]

The plot code :

```
% Created by tikzDevice version 0.10.1 on 2017-01-06 12:03:19
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
  \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
  \path[use as bounding box,fill=fillColor,fill opacity=0.00] (0,0) rectangle (361.35,361.35);
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (361.35,361.35);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 0.6pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (  0.00,  0.00) rectangle (361.35,361.35);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] ( 18.58, 18.58) rectangle ( 47.35,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] ( 18.58, 18.58) rectangle ( 47.35,338.79);

    \path[] ( 50.72,139.44) -- ( 32.96,178.68);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{50,78,104}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.95] at ( 54.44,124.47) {crooked};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at ( 54.46,181.70) {president};

    \path[] ( 42.68,174.48) -- ( 32.96,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at ( 58.05,162.70) {megynkelly};

    \path[] ( 32.41,152.64) -- ( 32.96,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.13] at ( 32.30,143.33) {bad};

    \path[] ( 39.74,312.20) -- ( 32.96,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.57] at ( 39.92,313.70) {cnn};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] ( 52.85, 18.58) rectangle ( 81.63,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] ( 52.85, 18.58) rectangle ( 81.63,338.79);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{25,9,140}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.13] at ( 76.34,160.77) {york};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.06] at (-26.96,170.52) {makeamericagreatagain};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at ( 61.48,182.08) {people};

    \path[] ( 67.08,223.32) -- ( 67.24,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at ( 67.06,224.83) {vote};

    \path[] ( 67.29,156.21) -- ( 67.24,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at ( 67.30,146.29) {am};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] ( 87.13, 18.58) rectangle (115.91,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] ( 87.13, 18.58) rectangle (115.91,338.79);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{50,78,104}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  3.41] at ( 55.49,171.91) {crooked};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.76] at ( 75.71,156.68) {bernie};

    \path[] ( 80.21,150.87) -- (101.52,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.50] at ( 72.46,132.15) {sanders};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.13] at ( 95.71,186.74) {bad};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.83] at (100.58,145.49) {isis};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (121.41, 18.58) rectangle (150.19,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] (121.41, 18.58) rectangle (150.19,338.79);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{46,97,145}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  3.08] at ( 94.98,180.68) {nytimes};

    \path[] (122.61,150.72) -- (135.80,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.13] at (118.43,134.52) {failing};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.10] at (119.76,160.17) {media};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (130.13,201.55) {story};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at (130.04,183.11) {people};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (155.69, 18.58) rectangle (184.46,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] (155.69, 18.58) rectangle (184.46,338.79);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{40,81,119}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.50] at (139.07,162.98) {america};

    \path[] (154.69,199.07) -- (170.07,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.06] at (148.19,200.57) {indiana};

    \path[] (156.82,158.46) -- (170.07,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.03] at (151.25,142.98) {warren};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (166.31,163.39) {vote};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at (152.24,183.01) {elizabeth};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (189.96, 18.58) rectangle (218.74,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] (189.96, 18.58) rectangle (218.74,338.79);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{43,78,112}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.68] at (191.13,166.55) {vote};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.30] at (161.12,168.44) {drainthesw};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.83] at (197.91,192.71) {time};

    \path[] (196.04,209.85) -- (204.35,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (194.21,211.36) {florida};

    \path[] (198.33,161.38) -- (204.35,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (195.95,149.21) {watch};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (224.24, 18.58) rectangle (253.02,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] (224.24, 18.58) rectangle (253.02,338.79);

    \path[] (258.49,197.94) -- (238.63,178.68);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{57,90,122}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  3.01] at (270.73,199.44) {debate};

    \path[] (253.06,215.58) -- (238.63,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.78] at (257.39,217.09) {team};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.23] at (179.28,169.01) {bigleaguetruth};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.75] at (220.40,163.00) {america};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (264.64,181.67) {mikepence};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (258.52, 18.58) rectangle (287.30,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] (258.52, 18.58) rectangle (287.30,338.79);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{65,90,114}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.58] at (240.88,180.52) {crooked};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.60] at (275.53,148.12) {wall};

    \path[] (264.33,202.81) -- (272.91,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.60] at (261.83,204.32) {people};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.30] at (262.62,165.17) {country};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.22] at (266.77,182.71) {border};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (292.80, 18.58) rectangle (321.57,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] (292.80, 18.58) rectangle (321.57,338.79);

    \path[] (298.67,158.70) -- (307.18,178.68);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{78,106,132}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (295.60,145.82) {florida};

    \path[] (298.73,181.39) -- (307.18,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.65] at (276.26,182.90) {americafirst};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.55] at (304.37,162.39) {ohio};

    \path[] (300.58,198.79) -- (307.18,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.43] at (298.46,200.30) {people};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.37] at (297.08,181.82) {tonight};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (327.07, 18.58) rectangle (355.85,338.79);
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[fill=fillColor] (327.07, 18.58) rectangle (355.85,338.79);

    \path[] (319.30,199.15) -- (341.46,178.68);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{102,144,183}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  2.66] at (307.76,200.66) {america};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.83] at (345.10,157.02) {join};

    \path[] (333.70,190.74) -- (341.46,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at (329.43,192.25) {tonight};

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.49] at (314.64,175.93) {americafirst};

    \path[] (329.49,152.50) -- (341.46,178.68);

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  1.13] at (327.01,143.18) {imwithyou};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] ( 18.58,338.79) rectangle ( 47.35,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 18.58,338.79) rectangle ( 47.35,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 32.96,344.29) {topic0};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] ( 52.85,338.79) rectangle ( 81.63,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 52.85,338.79) rectangle ( 81.63,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at ( 67.24,344.29) {topic1};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] ( 87.13,338.79) rectangle (115.91,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] ( 87.13,338.79) rectangle (115.91,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (101.52,344.29) {topic2};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (121.41,338.79) rectangle (150.19,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (121.41,338.79) rectangle (150.19,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (135.80,344.29) {topic3};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (155.69,338.79) rectangle (184.46,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (155.69,338.79) rectangle (184.46,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (170.07,344.29) {topic4};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (189.96,338.79) rectangle (218.74,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (189.96,338.79) rectangle (218.74,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (204.35,344.29) {topic5};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    \path[clip] (224.24,338.79) rectangle (253.02,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{fillColor}{RGB}{255,255,255}

    \path[draw=drawColor,line width= 1.1pt,line join=round,line cap=round,fill=fillColor] (224.24,338.79) rectangle (253.02,355.85);
    \definecolor{drawColor}{gray}{0.10}

    \node[text=drawColor,anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, scale=  0.88] at (238.63,344.29) {topic6};
  \end{scope}
  % \begin{scope}
  %   \path[clip] (258.52,338.79) rectangle (287.30,355.85);
  %   \definecolor{draw}
  % \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "help"
%%% End:
```

Comment: Thank u. I might have solved all my problem using R sweave.